# When i perform click operation on this button it executes but the popup fails to appear?

Tags: c#-4.0, selenium-webdriver

[image]

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("editBtCpTask-btnE1")).Click();
```

Comment: Have you tried using another locator? If yes, do you get any error message or what happens exactly?

Comment: well its like the above command gets executed and  then it throws an exception for the next command that is to be executed. NoElementFoundException is created for the next command

Comment: Please try using this locator: By.XPath("//button[@id='editBtCpTask-btnE1']")